# Add Action is disabled in navigation (android Studio 3.3 )?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, jitpack

I just started to implement navigation in my android app and `add action`  button or the circle to drag from it, disabled in navigation design view as below, 
and as you can see also `Set as Start Destination` is also disabled,
how to enable it?

[image]